# C++ How to handle copy of objects with destructor that damages the state?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if I've worded this correctly.

Basically, I have a class like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        CreateHandle(&m_handle);
    }

    ~A() 
    { 
        DeleteHandle(&m_handle); 
    }

private:
    Handle m_handle;
}
```

And it's a member of another class:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(int data) : m_data(data) {} 
    /* ... */

private:
    A m_a;
    int m_data;
}
```

And finally I have a third class which is sort of like a container of `B`s:

```
class C
{
public:
    /* ... */
    void AddOneB(B b)
    {
        m_bs.push_back(b);
    }        

private:
    std::vector<B> m_bs;
}
```

Lastly, in my code where I'm creating a `C` instance, I would do something like this:

```
...
C cObj;
cObj.AddOneB( B(23) );
...
```

My problem is that the destructor of `A` actually destroys the memory that it created in it's constructor. So doing this results in my `cObj` getting a `B` with an `A` that it no good.

My first thought was to make the instance of `A` in `B` a `std::shared_ptr`, but I was wondering if there's any other, paradigm (is that the word), to handle situations like this?

I can't see how copy constructors or move constructors can help here because the destructor will be called regardless.

Comment: I'm missing the subtle reason why it would not solve the problem to give class `A` a copy constructor that gives the copy its own, independent `Handle` instance.

Comment: I cannot get your problem. `the destructor of A actually destroys the memory that it created in it's constructor`. That is how things should be done, isn't it?

Comment: You should fix this in `A`, not in its users, but *how* you do that would depend on the nature of the `Handle` type. Can it be shared or copied or should each handle be unique?

Comment: The Handle is just an identifier to the actual memory of what's being created, it's just an `unsigned int`. You can't move the memory to a different Handle, or even if you did (like, copy the `unsigned int`) the destructor is still going to destruct the Handle.

Comment: If it helps at all, these are `GLuint`s from OpenGL. These are being created via calls to `glGenX`. I didn't want to complicate the question by including OpenGL references so I attempted to abstract it away. Maybe it's helps though.

Comment: Turning `A` into a `std::shared_ptr` data member of `B` solves the problem.  What drawbacks worry you about that?

Comment: None, I was only wanting to know what else I could do. Using OpenGL my code gets littered with `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Some versions of the pImpl idiom do that. Instead of having `Impl *pImpl`, you can write `Impl &impl` and then you get to use `.` instead of `->` when using your implementation, which is a little syntax nicety.  At the end of it you `delete &impl;` instead of `delete pImpl`.

Comment: (although that is nothing to do with this question, there is no deleting of references here)

Comment: @MattMcNabb - "At the end of it you delete &impl;"  Oh... the '&' in the delete statement I did not notice.  And now it seems to be gone, anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a choice: either `A` has **unique ownership** of the `Handle`, or it has **shared ownership** of it.

If the former, you need to make `A` noncopyable. For exactly the problems you present in your question. If C++11, you should make it movable:

```
A(const A&) = delete;
A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

A(A&& rhs) {
   // transfer ownership of m_handle from rhs to this
   // so that rhs doesn't destroy it
}
```

If the latter, you need to reference count the `Handle` so that only one of the copies of `A` destroys it:

```
class A {
    int* refCnt;
    Handle m_handle;

public:
    A()
    {
        CreateHandle(&m_handle);
        refCnt = new int(1);
    }

    A(const A& rhs)
    : m_handle(rhs.m_handle)
    , refCnt(rhs.refCnt)
    {
        (*refCnt)++; // now we have an additional reference
    }

    ~A() {
        if (--*refCnt == 0) {
            // only destroy if we're the LAST one
            DeleteHandle(&m_handle);
        }
    }
};
```

Shared ownership is more expensive (and what I wrote above is not thread-safe, if that's a concern), so pick the one that makes the most definitely. Definitely you cannot have a copyable type that expresses have unique ownership - that is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Barry. For anyone who comes along this in future, this was for OpenGL, and after transferring the `Handle`/`GLuint` values to the new object, the old object needs them set to `0` or something so that it's destructor doesn't delete someones memory.

Comment: In practice I'd recommend using `shared_ptr<A>` with the original `A` , instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yeah, it actually turns out that's what I had to do as there was always a case when I needed to copy-assign an `A` (I need to use `A` in `std::container`s). I could've safely invalidated the state of the rhs in a copy constructor or something (maybe), but I didn't like that idea in case it came back to bite me in the future.